# No braces around one-line if in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, code-formatting, netbeans-8

After I'm done writing some code, or when someone else has pushed code to the repository, I like to quickly run NetBeans' code formatting over the code. I've managed to customise it to my needs, except for one thing;

When this is in the code...

```
if ($a == $b)
    $c = $d;
```

... NetBeans will reformat it as follows;

```
if ($a == $b)
{
    $c = $d;
}
```

In my opinion, it just makes the code less readable. I've messed around in the code formatting preferences, but I haven't found an option to do this.

So how do I tell NetBeans' code formatter to not add braces (or even remove them if they're there, ideally) around `if` statements that consist of a single line?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in NetBeans but I also don't think it's a real problem. Just do NOT reformat the code -- or let it be with the curly braces.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Code formatting can be really useful when working on a project with other people (or when the code you wrote the night before was alcohol- or sleep-induced).

Comment: Code formatting is very important, not so much when first written, but much later when someone else (even you) has to maintain the code.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you how to get NetBeans to treat single line blocks the way you want. What I can offer is a reasoning, why NetBeans is doing this (add braces). A single line block without braces is dangerous. If somebody else is adding another line to the if-block without adding the braces they will be in for a surprise. Remember the ["goto fail"](https://www.google.de/search?q=goto+fail) Bug a couple of weeks ago? That's what happens, if you don't <del>eat</del> add your braces.

Comment: Mistakes can and will always be made. Coding style is a personal preference, and each and every one of them have advantages and disadvantages :) I personally think more mistakes will come from unreadable code than from not using curly braces around every `if` statement. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but this answer could be useful.
I'm using NetBeans 11.2 for programming Java code and I had same "problem", after little search I found this in **Tools > Options > Editor**:

[image]