# Remove unnecessary braces

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there's a way in NetBeans to remove unnecessary braces in one-line statements?

I would like to convert something like this:

```
if (something) {
    doSomething();
}
```

to

```
if (something) doSomething();
```

I do this manually all the time, but sometimes I have to format the code for some other reasons using `alt+shift+f` command and netbeans adds those braces again.

**If is not possible**, Is there a way to tell the formatter not to add those braces when I press the `alt+shift+f` command? I know Eclipse do this, and I would like to know if Netbeans can.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3718670/3998458) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23847770/3998458) answers, and apparently it can't be done, but both are php oriented; this apply to java too?

Comment: this is a **terrible** practice, there is no such thing as *unnecessary* braces, they are *optional* but to avoid subtle impossible to trace bugs and to make things **explicit** as possible for future maintenance, they are always **necessary**! - `if (something) { doSomething(); }` is **much preferred** if you really just want everything on a single line! IntelliJ IDEA does this easily.

Comment: Re-iterating what @JarrodRoberson has said; you should **never** leave statements without braces. It's **very bad practice** and leaves the potential to introduce unintended behaviors (*bugs*) later on, then making debugging a potential nightmare. Also, +1 Jarrod

Comment: @EvanBechtol @Jarrod Roberson, It is still a bad design if I do the `if (something) { doSomething(); }` in the same line (without the line brake and indent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.  If you don't have the exact same version, hopefully you'll find that the following steps are similar enough to make it work for you.

1. Go to `Tools --> Options`.
2. Click on the top `Editor` button.
3. Go to `Formatting` tab.
4. Make sure the `Language` combo box has `Java` selected.
5. Modify the value of the `Category` combo box to `Braces`.
6. Under `Braces Generation`, change the value for `if:` to `Eliminate`.

After you apply these changes, formatting the code will correctly remove the braces for single line statements, and leave them for multi line statements.

You can do the same for other keywords like `for` or `while` if you want.

**EDIT**

Since a few heated comments were made on the question itself about the validity of such a request, I'd like to make a comment of my own on the topic of the practice of coding `if-else` statements without braces.

I personally ***always*** use braces, even if it means typing a little more, and wasting a little more screen space. As already mentioned, it is so much safer to do so.  The clarity to the code it provides far outweighs any cosmetic benefits.

That said, I respect that it is still a matter of personal preference, especially if you are the only one maintaining the code. Also, if you have the good habit of auto-formatting your code, then that will minimize any risks associated with misinterpreting the blocks of codes without braces, because the auto-formatter will indent the code appropriately.

But if you work in a team environment, I think it would be very considerate on your part to consider leaving the braces in.

Comment: Thanks, I guess your answer, far for only say this is a bad practice, accept that there are personal preferences. I know this could be a problem in big projects or in teams, I read it in the answers that I append, but I'm the only one who have access to the project, and I was curious if NetBeans could do this automatically. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround:

You can use the formatter on just certain sections of the code.  Highlight just the function you want format.

Comment: Even if not the answer that I was looking, it helps me, I didn't know that.